# Convert datetime to PST timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

How can I make datetime converted into PST timezone? Not trying to use external librarys such as arrow. Also tried using timedelta but that also doesn't work for what I'm trying to do.

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
```

Comment: It is not clear what is your input and what is your output. `datetime.today()` does not contain time zone information, so it is impossible to convert that to a specific timezone without knowing the original time zone. And once you strip the time to get only a date, then there is no way to calculate date in another time zone, because that depends on time.

Answer (score 0):

PST is 8 hours behind UTC, so you can do something like this:

```
import datetime as dt
PST_timezone = dt.timezone(dt.timedelta(hours=-8))
PST_now = dt.datetime(1,1,1).now(PST_timezone) # arguments to datetime() don't matter
```

`dt.timezone()` let's you create your own time zones relative to UTC, which is easier to work with in general. `datetime.now()` operates similarly to `today()`, but accepts a timezone as an argument.