# How to convert datetime.date to PST timezone?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

```
Date = dt.datetime.today().date()
```

I have a date here but it's in UTC, for example at PST 2022-09-18 5PM it will turn into 2022-09-19, but I want to convert it into PST time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802069/convert-datetime-to-pst-timezone try like this

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `timezone` aware datetime - a naive datetime (like `datetime.date`) has no `timezone` information.
So, use a `datetime.datetime` with a `tzinfo`, and then you can localize to UTC and convert to Pacific time:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

pst = tz.gettz('America/Los_Angeles')

dt = datetime(2016, 1, 1, tzinfo=tz.UTC)
pst_dt = dt.astimezone(pst)
```

This gives you a datetime representing `2016-01-01 00:00:00` in the Pacific timezone.
You can of course start out with a naive datetime and use replace to add a UTC timezone:

```
dt = datetime(2016, 1, 1).replace(tzinfo=tz.UTC)
```

Comment: check out the [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module.